# Interfacing with unverified contracts with unknown function names (solved)

Tags: solidity

So I'm trying to make a helper-contract of sorts that should interface with some unverified contract on chain.
There is a getter function I'm interested in that I know the signature, arguments and return types of.
I also know that it is a view function.

Is there any way of calling such a function from a contract as read-only? (i.e. not pay gas)
I tried using address.call but it gives me a compiler error that the function cannot be view since it possibly alters the state.

Or is it possible to explicitly assign an interface function its signature? (I guess not :P)

As a last resort I'm thinking I should brute-force function names until I get one that produces the specific signature, and use that in the interface.
This seems a bit silly, but should work, right? There's only 4 billion different signatures (well, 4b per argument-set). Shouldn't take that many hours I guess.

Or does a rainbow table of method signatures already exist? (I'm aware of 4byte.directory but it's for the actual human-readable names of functions, not just any gibberish that produces it :P)

```
interface IUnknownContract {
    function unknownName() external view returns (uint); // 0xbabababa
}

contract Explorer {
    address constant target = 0x1333333333333333333333333333333333333337;
    
    function getUnknown() external view returns (uint) {
        return IUnknownContract(target).unknownName();
    }
    
    function getUnknownWithCall() external view returns (uint) {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = target.staticcall(abi.encodeWithSelector(0xbabababa));
        // issue fixed: use staticcall instead of call

        return abi.decode(data, (uint));
    }
}
```

Comment: For `view` functions you should use the `staticcall` instruction. Check [View functions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#view-functions) and [EVM-dialect](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/yul.html#evm-dialect).

Comment: Oh wow, I suck at reading API docs. This fixed my issue. Thanks :P